# string[::-1] means in python 3.6.2?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

What does this expression mean: `string[::-1]` in python.
Here is the sample code:

```
def reverse_string(string): return string[::-1]
```

I know this is used for reversing a string, but how does this expression work?

Comment: Did you try running the code to see what it does?

Comment: Yes. It prints the reversed form of that string. @coldspeed

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ use your new gold badge and close that if you please ? (I cannot, _I_ added the missing python tag)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ooh, didn't know dupe hammers could be nerfed like that :0

Comment: once in a while I teach you something :) you can also add more target original questions just in case someone questions the relevance of this particular original question.